# Parsing a couple JSON responses

Tags: json, vb.net

I've got two json responses that I'm trying to get some values from but I can't seem to figure out the coding syntax.

This is the first response:

```
{"temperature":{"poolTemp":47,"spaTemp":47,"airTemp":57,"solarTemp":0,"freeze":0}}
```

This is the second response:

```
{"pump":{"1":{"pump":1,"name":"Pump 1","drivestate":0,"watts":1458,"rpm":2850}}}
```

My platform is homeseer and this is code I'm trying to parse poolTemp from the first response:

```js
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Sub Main(parm as object)
    
Dim strReturn As String = hs.GetURL(“192.168.1.50”,”/temperature/”, FALSE, 3000)
Dim obj as New JObject

obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strReturn)
Dim strpoolTemp as String = obj.Value(Of JObject)("1").Value(Of String)("poolTemp")

End Sub
```

I assumed this code would work but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

If I am parsing this response:

```
{"number":2,"numberStr":"circuit2","name":"POOL LIGHT","circuitFunction":"Generic","status":0,"freeze":0,"macro":0,"delay":0,"friendlyName":"POOL LIGHT"}
```

This code works:

```js
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Sub Main(parm as object)
    
Dim strReturn As String = hs.GetURL(“192.168.1.50”,”/circuit/2/”, FALSE, 3000)
Dim obj as New Object
Dim strStatus as String
obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strReturn)
strStatus = obj.Item("status").ToString
hs.WriteLog("LightStatus",strStatus)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim parsedJson As JObject = JObject.Parse(strReturn) Dim result As String = parsedJson(0).Children.First().Value(Of String)("poolTemp")`

Comment: Or directly as an Integer: `Dim parsedJson As JToken = JObject.Parse(strReturn).First  Dim result As Integer = parsedJson.First.Value(Of Integer)("poolTemp")`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did what I needed.

```js
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json
Sub Main(p As String)
Dim strReturn As String = hs.GetURL(“192.168.1.50”,”/temperature/”, FALSE, 3000)
Dim obj As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strReturn)
Dim temperature As Object = obj.Item("temperature")
hs.WriteLog("temperature", temperature.ToString)
Dim airTemp As String = temperature.Item("airTemp").ToString
hs.WriteLog("airTemp", airTemp)
End Sub
```

```js
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
IMPORTS Newtonsoft.Json
Sub Main(p As String)
Dim strReturn As String = hs.GetURL(“192.168.1.50”,”/pump/”, FALSE, 3000)
Dim obj As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strReturn)
Dim pump As Object = obj.Item("pump")
hs.WriteLog("pump", pump.ToString)
Dim one as Object = pump.Item("1").ToString
hs.WriteLog("one", one.ToString)
Dim obj2 As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(one.ToString)
Dim rpm As String = obj2.Item("rpm").ToString
hs.WriteLog("rpm", rpm)
End Sub
```